# User cannot see directory permissions

Tags: permissions, directory, ls

I'm working in Ubuntu 3.13.

The permissions on a drive are such that the owner can see directories and files with these permissions:

```
drwxrwxr-x    2 michael atlas    4096 Feb 15 12:34 temp2
drwxrwxr-x    2 michael atlas   12288 Mar 18 16:14 temp3
```

while another member (ubuntu) of the group 'atlas' sees this:

```
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? temp2
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? temp3
```

unless ubuntu uses `sudo ls -l`, then the owner, group, and permissions look the same as when michael does an `ls -l`.

Here it can be seen the two users are in the same group:

```
ubuntu@lincloud:~$ grep '^atlas' /etc/group
atlas:x:1001:ubuntu,michael
```

What is the cause of the problem? 
How do I fix it?

Comment: check LANG variable

Comment: What's Ubuntu 3.13? Do you mean Ubuntu 13.04?

Comment: uname -a
3.13.0-48-generic #80-Ubuntu SMP Thu Mar 12 11:16:15 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: That's Ubuntu 14.04. 3.13 is the version of the kernel, not the Ubuntu version.

Comment: If not uname, what would I use to get the info that it's Ubuntu 14.04?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parent directory of temp2 and temp3 is where the issue lies.

Your atlas group has read permissions on the parent directory and you need read AND execute in order to see the files and their permissions.

if you're in the directory with temp2 and temp3 you can fix the issue with the following command:

```
sudo chmod g+x .
```

Comment: That worked. What is 'best practice'?

Comment: It depends on what is in the directory and what security is needed.  I'd say 750 or 770 (drwxr-x--- or drwxrwx--- respectively)

Answer (score 0):

The attributes of file are stored in inode data structure which is related a inode number, such as permission, size, uid, gid( by `ls -l` and `lsattr`). file name isn't stored in the inode data structure.
it is stored in the directory file, which is related a inode number.
`[luchaoqun@centos-7 ~]$ ls -i www
1704095 overflow_1  8722125 overflow_2`

If both `r` and `x` permission are set on the directory, you can see the file name and inode information (by `ls -i` command). if there are `r` permission, not `x` permission, you only can see the file name, and can't see inode information in the directory.

`[lu@centos-7 www]$ ls -l
total 8
-rw-r--r--. 1 luchaoqun luchaoqun 0 Jun  3 13:19 overflow_1
-rw-r--r--. 1 luchaoqun luchaoqun 0 Jun  3 13:19 overflow_2`

`[lu@centos-7 ~]$chmod u-x
[lu@centos-7 ~]$ ls -ld www
drw-r-xr-x. 2 luchaoqun luchaoqun 40 Jun  3 13:19 www
[lu@centos-7 ~]$ ls -l www
ls: cannot access www/overflow_1: Permission denied
ls: cannot access www/overflow_2: Permission denied
total 0
?????????? ? ? ? ?            ? overflow_1
?????????? ? ? ? ?            ? overflow_2`